# Created By update when user enters data

Tags: sql-server, triggers

How can i get the `CreatedBy` column to update with name of the user that has created a new `row` in a database? I have created a `Trigger` that adds a `ModifiedDate` when the user changes data in a `row` .
My Trigger;

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgUpdate
ON Table1
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0   RETURN
IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(object_ID('trgUpdate')) > 1  RETURN;
SET NOCOUNT  ON;



UPDATE Table1
SET    ModifiedOn = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM   Table1 c
   INNER JOIN INSERTED i
     ON c.accID = i.accID
END
```

Comment: How do your users authenticate against the DB? Are they all using one sql login or do they each have their own login?

Comment: they each have their own login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [System_User](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx)

Update table1 
    set ModifiedBy = [System_User](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx)()